# Google Map returning null Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am calling a method that requires an activity context from a non activity class. When I call that method, the Google Map that the activity hosts returns null, however it does not return null in the onCreate. I have tried adding context to it however it is not working.

Here is my code for the non Activity Class

```
Activity a = new Activty();
a.createMarker();
```

Then in the activity class 'a'

```
    public void createMarker()
{
    Drawable iconDrawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    final Bitmap iconBmp = ((BitmapDrawable) iconDrawable).getBitmap();


        Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(lattitude, longitude))
                .title(title)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(iconBmp)));


}
```

Comment: Can you provide a LogCat?

Comment: Did you try using an interface? Also if you call the method in a fragment, do you check if the activity is created?